# font size on math.se

Tags: bug, status-norepro

When i change the font size in the browser setting (Mozilla) it is getting reflecting on other pages but not on math.se page ? please explain what could be wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your browser and clearing your cache? In any event, you've given incomplete information: you neglected to mention the version of your browser and what OS you're on.

Comment: FireFox Ver 3.6.7, Mozilla Firefox for ubuntu Canonical -1.0.  OS : Ubuntu 10.04, tried restarting the broweser. The change in font is reflected on other pages but not on math.se.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem could be, but have you tried View > Zoom > Reset while on math.SE?

Answer (score 1):

Remember there are two kinds of browser zoom

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-two-types-of-browser-zoom.html

Which one are you using?

1. If you are using "zoom text only", we support -1, 0, +1.
2. If you are using "full page zoom", which is generally the default nowadays, you should be able to zoom to any size the browser supports.